# Android - trying to make a scrolling view and it is crashing

Tags: android, android-layout

I have this view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >

<ScrollView
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"    >    

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/page_exlain"    
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Lots of text here"
    android:layout_marginTop ="20dp" 
    />          



<TextView
    android:id="@+id/exec_summary_heading"    
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/light_best_blue"
    android:layout_marginTop ="10dp" 
        android:text="1) EXECUTIVE SUMMARY"
    />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/exec_summary_text"    
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Lots of text goes here."
    android:layout_marginTop ="10dp"    
    />              


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/product_heading"    
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/light_best_blue"
    android:layout_marginTop ="10dp"    
        android:text="2) YOUR PRODUCT OR SERVICE"
    />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/product_text"    
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Lots of text goes here......"
    android:layout_marginTop ="10dp"    
    />    



</ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

This crashes.  Any idea why?  I am not sure how to make the whole page scrollable.

Thanks!

Comment: make a child layout for scrollview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put your textviews inside another layout, like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >

<ScrollView
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"    >    


<LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/page_exlain"    
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Lots of text here"
    android:layout_marginTop ="20dp" 
    />          



<TextView
    android:id="@+id/exec_summary_heading"    
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/light_best_blue"
    android:layout_marginTop ="10dp" 
        android:text="1) EXECUTIVE SUMMARY"
    />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/exec_summary_text"    
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Lots of text goes here."
    android:layout_marginTop ="10dp"    
    />              


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/product_heading"    
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/light_best_blue"
    android:layout_marginTop ="10dp"    
        android:text="2) YOUR PRODUCT OR SERVICE"
    />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/product_text"    
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Lots of text goes here......"
    android:layout_marginTop ="10dp"    
    />    

</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

(you need to remove the line `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` on Scrollview)

Answer (score 3):

scrollview can have only one direct child

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >

<ScrollView
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"    >    

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/page_exlain"    
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Lots of text here"
    android:layout_marginTop ="20dp" 
    />          



<TextView
    android:id="@+id/exec_summary_heading"    
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/light_best_blue"
    android:layout_marginTop ="10dp" 
        android:text="1) EXECUTIVE SUMMARY"
    />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/exec_summary_text"    
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Lots of text goes here."
    android:layout_marginTop ="10dp"    
    />              


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/product_heading"    
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/light_best_blue"
    android:layout_marginTop ="10dp"    
        android:text="2) YOUR PRODUCT OR SERVICE"
    />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/product_text"    
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Lots of text goes here......"
    android:layout_marginTop ="10dp"    
    />    


</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use it like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >

<ScrollView
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"    >  

  <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/page_exlain"    
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Lots of text here"
    android:layout_marginTop ="20dp" 
    />          



<TextView
    android:id="@+id/exec_summary_heading"    
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/light_best_blue"
    android:layout_marginTop ="10dp" 
        android:text="1) EXECUTIVE SUMMARY"
    />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/exec_summary_text"    
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Lots of text goes here."
    android:layout_marginTop ="10dp"    
    />              


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/product_heading"    
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/light_best_blue"
    android:layout_marginTop ="10dp"    
        android:text="2) YOUR PRODUCT OR SERVICE"
    />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/product_text"    
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Lots of text goes here......"
    android:layout_marginTop ="10dp"    
    />    

</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

The reason is that a `ScrollView` in Android can only host 1 child at a time.. So you would have to put all of your `TextView`s that you want to scroll in a Container like a `LinearLayout` again.

Comment: For some reason, in my case the textview elements dont show up :(

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at these simple examples on creating a simple listview and complex custom listviews.

[Creating scrolling ListView in android](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/03/12/creating-scrolling-listview-in-android/)

and this one for more complex.

[Android listView with icons](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/03/25/android-image-listview/)

in-android/